# How to get all empty values with null in document.find() mongodb along with existing values

Tags: mongodb, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I am querying and retrieving all data from a collection to json . The collection has 50 fields.But all 50 fields are not filled in the records. When I retrieve the record to json ,I am getting only existing fields .. For example if name is not there in the document,it wont be there.. I want it to come as {'name':'null'}.

As there are 50 fields,it is difficult to do a manual check..

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use aggregation to overcome this issue. `$addFields` will do this for you. But keep in mind that you need to add all the keys in your condition. This is the only way, I could think of to achieve your result.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      name: {
        $cond: [ { $type: 'string' }, '$name', 'null' ]
      },
      age: {
        $cond: [ { $type: 'number' }, '$age', 'null' ]
      },
      /* ...other fields */
    }
  }
])
```

These will overwrite the existing fields, for the value you want.